# WPF: StringFormat problems with a Label

Tags: wpf, binding

These versions work as expected:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Units" Binding="{Binding TotalUnits, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=N0}"/>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalUnits, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=N0}"/>
```

When I try it with a label, the StringFormat is iqnored and I get "123.000000" instead of "123".

```
<Label Content="{Binding TotalUnits, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=N0}"/>
```

TotalUnits is a Decimal.

So, what's going on?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Anything with a `Content` property has a special `ContentStringFormat` property you have to use rather than specifying the StringFormat in the Binding.

Like this:

```
<Window.Resources xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <sys:Int16 x:Key="MyValue">100</sys:Int16>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource MyValue}">

    <!-- using Label -->
    <Label Content="{Binding}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0:C}" />

    <!-- using TextBlock-->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding, StringFormat={0:C}}" />

</StackPanel>
```