# Correct syntax for a Binding's StringFormat

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting

Been trying to format a string using BindingBase.StringFormat but I can't get it to display custom formatting. Tried to escape or not brackets, using quotes or not, binding to a string property but none proved to be working.

The following should display "hi !!!" but remains "hi" :

```
<Label Tag="hi" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Tag, StringFormat='\{0\} !!!'}" />
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3826761/620360

Comment: Try prefixing your expression with empty brackets: `StringFormat='{}{0} !!!'`

Comment: @EsotericScreenName tried that already but unfortunately it didn't work either.